# Is there a way to remember the clicked state of one of numerous buttons after navigating away from the home page?

Tags: jquery

I have a dropdown menu which contains numerous buttons. And when one of these buttons is clicked, it changes the page's overall background image and two other images along with it. Each of these buttons are linked to different images. What I want to achieve is that if someone clicks one of these buttons, that it's remembered when people navigate to any other page on the same site.

Rather unfamiliar with jQuery (only very recently dabbling into it), so my attempts have been rather... simple. I feel that my solution lies with sessionStorage of some sort, but I've been unsuccessful in applying it to my script, as it contains multiple buttons/options. This is the script I'm working with:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('.tony').on({
'click': function(){
$('.sidebarimgtop').attr('src','https://i.imgur.com/tJPF58T.png');
$('.sidebarimgbottom').attr('src','https://i.imgur.com/7pPbjpR.png');
$("body").css('background-image', 'url(https://i.imgur.com/WOqyufE.png)');
 }   

$('.ezio').on({
'click': function(){
$('.sidebarimgtop').attr('src','https://i.imgur.com/orXH355.png');
$('.sidebarimgbottom').attr('src','https://i.imgur.com/CWXpT1c.png');
$("body").css('background-image', 'url(https://i.imgur.com/UEiclnW.png)');
 }

$('.oberyn').on({
'click': function(){
$('.sidebarimgtop').attr('src','https://i.imgur.com/ragcux5.png');
$('.sidebarimgbottom').attr('src','https://i.imgur.com/tToH5jK.png');
$("body").css('background-image', 'url(https://i.imgur.com/l21z868.png)');
 }
});    
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

[Local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) is what you're probably going to want to use for this. For each of your onclick events, you'll want to add the a line saving the class name of what was clicked, like this:

```
$('.oberyn').on('click', function () {
    localStorage.setItem('background-style', 'oberyn');

    // your code
})
```

And then, in the onready function, you'll want to check that value and apply the matching sets of images

```
$(document).on('ready', function () {
  if (localStorage.getItem('background-style') !== '') {
    let style = localStorage.getItem('background-style');

    switch (style) {
      case 'tony':
        $('.sidebarimgtop').attr('src', 'https://i.imgur.com/ragcux5.png');
        $('.sidebarimgbottom').attr('src', 'https://i.imgur.com/tToH5jK.png');
        $("body").css('background-image', 'url(https://i.imgur.com/l21z868.png)');
        break;
      case 'ezio':
        $('.sidebarimgtop').attr('src', 'https://i.imgur.com/orXH355.png');
        $('.sidebarimgbottom').attr('src', 'https://i.imgur.com/CWXpT1c.png');
        $("body").css('background-image', 'url(https://i.imgur.com/UEiclnW.png)');
        break;
      case 'oberyn':
        $('.sidebarimgtop').attr('src', 'https://i.imgur.com/ragcux5.png');
        $('.sidebarimgbottom').attr('src', 'https://i.imgur.com/tToH5jK.png');
        $("body").css('background-image', 'url(https://i.imgur.com/l21z868.png)');
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }
  }
});
```